# Basis of a set of polynomials in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Find a basis for the following vector space:

$W = \{p(t) \in P_3 \ | \ p(1) = p'(2)\}$.

I found an example to be $p(t) = t^3 − 3t^2 − 3t + 2$ is in $W$ since

$p(1) = 1 − 3 − 3 + 2 = −3$ and  $p'(t) = 3t^2 − 6t − 3$

so $p'(2) = 12 − 12 − 3 = −3$ also.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Try taking a general polynomial $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, apply the conditions given and get a system of linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

since the $dim(W) = 3$

you just need to find 3 linearly independent polynomials in $W$

one if $f(x) = x$

also $f(x) = x^2 +3$

and the third you can use your example

Comment: $\text{dim}[P]_3=4$

Comment: by the way, $dim(P_3)=4$, but you cannot find a fourth polynomial for the basis, thus $dim(W)=3$

Comment: I am sorry, wrote $P_3$ instead of $W$.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find a polynomial of every degre that satisfy the condition.

Degre 0 : the only polynomial with degre 0 that satisfies $p(1)=p\prime(2)$ is $p(t)=0$, not part of any basis.

Degre 1 : With $p(t) =  at+b$, $p^\prime(t)=a$.  Any polynomial with $b=0$ satisfies the condition.  $p(t)=t$ is part of the basis.

Degre 2 : with $p(t) = at^2+bt+c$, $p^\prime(t)=2at+b$.  The condition gives

$$a + b+c = 4a+b$$
$$c = 3a$$
Then $p(t)=t^2+3$ is part of the basis.

Finally, we have found three linearly independant vector and it is impossible to find a fourth one.
$$\{t, t^2+3, t^3-3t^2-3t+2\}$$